# What is the difference between these two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array `x` of shape `(N, d)`.

If I create the arrays `r_1` and `r_2` as follows, the outputs should be equal, which is true.

```
import numpy as np

N = 100
d = 2
x = np.random.rand(N, d)

r_1 = x.reshape(N, 1, d) - np.repeat(x[np.newaxis, :, :], N, axis=0)
r_2 = x.reshape(N, 1, d) - x.reshape(1, N, d)

print((r_1 == r_2).all())
> True
```

However, if I use the arrays in a deterministic simulation, the two methods yield different end results due to (I assume) floating point errors.
I did some digging into the simulation and everything is equal until the eighth iteration, in which I get differences such as:

```
Method 1: 0.4759682049387506
Method 2: 0.47596820493875036
```

And these floating point errors can propagate to quite different end results of the simulation:

```
Method 1:
E_kin:  11651.935893586868
E_pot:  -22091.50550903025
Method 2:
E_kin:  12059.81250826829
E_pot:  -21037.60706699791
```

What is the underlying difference between these two arrays that computations with them don't end up with the same results? Everything in the simulation is held constant except for whether or not method one or two is used for computing `r`.

Edit: This is using numpy version 1.18.1.

Comment: 1. Are these operations working as intended, mathematically? You are substracting arrays of different shapes, while Python allows this, results may not be what one would expect. 2. You can get different round-off error simply by having e.g. summations ordered differently. If your algorithm as a whole is this sensitive to round-off errors, you have some serious stability issues.

Comment: @PeterMeisrimel 1. Yes, they work as intended. I basically want `r[i, j]= x[i] - x[j]` which is what both broadcast operations are doing. I'm explicitly subtracting arrays of different shapes to take advantage of numpy's broadcasting. 2. I know about the summation ordering and such, but the way these arrays are created there should only be a single subtraction operation per entry. I agree about the stability issues, but it's a homework where I have to use a specific algorithm. It's a molecular dynamics simulation so any divergence in the states yields different physics past that point.

Comment: Those arrays are identical in every way as far as I can tell (values, shape, strides, flags, etc). Are you able to share the code for the simulation? Are you absolutely certain that it is deterministic, and have you tested this by running it repeatedly on the same input? Even a simulation that is "mathematically" deterministic may be non-deterministic if not implemented carefully. In particular, some BLAS libraries are non-deterministic.

Comment: @myrtlecat I am certain it is deterministic, each method produces the same results every time, and the only random part is seeded (initialization of positions and velocities). Here is the simulation class https://bpa.st/23CA and here is the file I'm using to test the differences https://bpa.st/CNQA. Namely, see line 117 of the simulation class file to see the difference between setting the `numpy_method` kwarg in the class instantiation in the test file.